# Average of array by using a callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, sum, average

I'm having a problem to sum and find the average of an array. I keep getting average is 0.
I cant really see what the problem could be :

```
var a = [10,20,30,40]
var sum = 0
var avg = 0
function sumUP(a) {
   for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      sum += a[i];
      avg = (sum/a.length);
   }
}
function display(avg, callback) {
   document.write("Average of array is " + avg)
   callback(average);   
}
display(avg, sumUP);
```

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You are displaying the value of *avg* before calling the function that sets it (and there are issues with what you pass in the call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning to global variables, you should have `sumUP` return the calculated average so it can be used in your `document.write`. That's one of the purposes of functions - to encapsulate functionality and return values that can be used by other functions without unnecessary side-effects. You also need to calculate the average *before* you display it. (you were displaying it *before* you were calculating it, which of course leaves it displaying `0`)

You should also take care not to use single-letter variable names, which are very hard to make sense of (not only for others reading your code, but also for you, when you come back to it later).

```js
const array = [10, 20, 30, 40];
function sumUP(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  const avg = (sum / arr.length);
  return avg;
}
function display(arr, callback) {
  const avg = callback(arr);
  document.write("Average of array is " + avg)
}
display(array, sumUP);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write code like this.

```
function sumUP(a) {
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
sum += a[i];
}
avg = (sum/a.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at : [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40]

const sum = arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b , 0)

const avg = sum / arr.length

function display(avg) {
   document.write("Average of array is " + avg)
}

display(avg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass `avg` to the `callback` and `display` function at all:

```js
var a = [10,20,30,40];
var sum = 0;
var avg = 0;
function sumUP() {
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    sum += a[i];
    res = (sum/a.length);
  }
}
function display(callback) {
  callback();
  document.write("Average of array is: " + res);
}
display(sumUP);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for your code.

```
var a = [10,20,30,40]
var sum = 0
var avg = 0
function sumUP(a) {
   for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      sum += a[i];
   }
   avg = (sum/a.length);
}
function display(callback) {
    callback(a);
    document.write("Average of array is " + avg);
}
display(sumUP);
```

The first problem in your code was you are calling the callback function after the document write. It should be called first before the writing the result because these method have your logic.

And the avg that you are calling is not the global variable that you declare but the variable that is being used by the function. I remove it in your parameter because it was already declared as global and no need to pass in the display function.

I also exlude `avg = (sum/a.length);` in the for loop because it can be computed once, and that is when the for loop is done or when you get the total sum of your numbers.